# What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left[\mathrm{ln}\left(\mathrm{det}\left( TQT^T+BI\right ) \right ) \right ]$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left[\mathrm{ln}\left(\mathrm{det}\left( TQT^T+BI\right ) \right ) \right ]$ (and how do I derive the answer in an intuitive way)? $T\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},Q_l\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},B\in\mathbb{R}$, and $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, so the answer should be $\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

For context, this arises from the following problem: $y=Tx+v$, with $y\in\mathbb{R}^{m},x\in\mathbb{R}^{n},v\in\mathbb{R}^m$, and $x$ and $v$ are random variables with distributions $p(x)=\mathcal{N}\left(x|\mu_x,Q \right )$ and $p(v)=\mathcal{N}\left(v|0,BI \right )$ respectively; how do I choose $T$ such that the mutual information between $x$ and $y$ is maximised (subject to some arbitrary constraint or regularisation term that is not included here, for example all the rows of $T$ have fixed Euclidean norm)? The mutual information can be expressed as $\mathbb{E}\left[\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{p(y|x)}{p(y)} \right )\right]$, which in this case involving Gaussian random variables simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{\det\left(\mathrm{Var}(y) \right )}{\det\left(\mathrm{Var}(y|x) \right )} \right ) = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{ln}\left(\frac{\det\left(TQT^T+BI \right )}{\det\left(BI \right )} \right )$, so I'm looking for the gradient in question in order to proceed with this optimisation. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you know the [matrix cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf)?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net thanks for the link; according to a couple of expressions from this cookbook, I think for the $ij$th element of the derivative, we have $\frac{\partial}{\partial T_{ij}}\left[\ln\left(\det\left( TQT^T+BI\right ) \right ) \right ] = \left( TQT^T+BI\right )^{-1}:\frac{\partial}{\partial T_{ij}}\left[TQT^T+BI \right] = \left( TQT^T+BI\right )^{-1}:\left(T^T QJ^{ij} + J^{ji}QT\right)=\mathrm{Tr}\left( \left( TQT^T+BI\right )^{-1}\left(T^T QJ^{ij} + J^{ji}QT\right)\right )$; do you (or anyone) know if this can be simplified into a general expression for the full matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\sym#1{\operatorname{sym}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
$For typing convenience, define the matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
F &= {TQT^T + BI} \\
}$$
Rewrite the function,
calculate its differential using [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula),
then extract the gradient
$$\eqalign{
\l &= \log(\det(F)) \\
\c{d\l} &\c{=} \c{\trace{F^{-1}dF}} \\
 &= \trace{F^{-1}\LR{dT\:QT^T+TQ\:dT^T}} \\
 &= \trace{2\,QT^TF^{-1}\,dT} \\
\grad{\l}{T} &= 2\,QT^TF^{-1} \\
}$$
Depending on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions),
you may wish to transpose this result.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I was familiar with the derivate of the logarithm of the determinant being equal to the inverse, the trick I was missing was to express $d\lambda$ in terms of $dF(T)=F(T+dT)-F(T)=((T+dT)Q(T+dT)^T+BI)-(TQT^T+BI)=TQdT^T+dTQT^T$